# Run pygame codes and it shows 'Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member' and white screen window

Tags: python, python-3.x, pygame

I am a beginner for learning Python and I just ran into a problem when I debug a series of codes I copied from a book, and I get a white screen window instead of one with pattern, here is the code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS
pygame.init()
windowWidth = 640
windowHeight = 480
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Shapes!')

while True:
    surface.fill((200, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0, 0), (random.randint(0, windowWidth), random.randint(0, windowHeight), 10, 10))

greenSquareX = windowWidth / 2
greenSquareY = windowHeight / 2

while True:
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 255, 0),
     (greenSquareX, greenSquareY, 10, 10))
    greenSquareX += 1
    # greenSquareY += 1
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 255),
       (blueSquareX, blueSquareY, 10, 10))

    blueSquareX = 0.0
    blueSquareY = 0.0
    blueSquareVX = 1
    blueSquareVy = 1

while True:
    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 255),
       (blueSquareX, blueSquareY, 10, 10))
    blueSquareX += blueSquareVX
    blueSquareY += blueSquareVY
    blueSquareVX += 0.1
    blueSquareVY += 0.1

    for event in GAME_EVENTS.GET():
        if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    pygame.dispaly.update()
```

And the first error I got was: `E1101:Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member'(4 ,1)`. I have ran other Python code with `pygame.init()` before, and the result turned out well; but this time I get a white screen window. What is wrong with my code? Thanks for help!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This took me a great deal of debugging to fix, haha.

First of all, you are not escaping or updating in any of your `while` loops. Once the code enters your first `while` loop, nothing (the `pygame.display`) ever updates after that – resulting in your white-screen syndrome.

In addition, please name your variables consistently and check for typos in your code. You created a `blueSquareVy` variable only to try to refer to it as `blueSquareVY` later, and you misspelled `pygame.display.update()` at the end of the code. Capitalization matters – and that's just a few of the typos!

There are also logical errors within the code. You should *not* fill your window surface after your graphics have been drawn onto the screen. Looking at your variables, it seems that you would like the little squares to move. You would create the position variables outside of the `while` loop, as if you create them within the loop, they get recreated at their initial value every iteration of the loop.

The annotated and bugfixed code:

```
import pygame, sys, random
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS
pygame.init()
windowWidth = 640
windowHeight = 480
surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Shapes!')

# Renamed variables to be consistent
# Moved variables out of the while loop
greenSquareX = windowWidth / 2
greenSquareY = windowHeight / 2
blueSquareX = 0.0
blueSquareY = 0.0
blueSquareVX = 1
blueSquareVY = 1

# Joined the two while loops into one
while True:
    surface.fill((200, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255, 0, 0), (random.randint(0, windowWidth), random.randint(0, windowHeight), 10, 10))

    surface.fill((0, 0, 0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 255, 0),
     (greenSquareX, greenSquareY, 10, 10))
    greenSquareX += 1
    greenSquareY += 1

    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (0, 0, 255),
       (blueSquareX, blueSquareY, 10, 10))
    blueSquareX += blueSquareVX
    blueSquareY += blueSquareVY
    blueSquareVX += 0.1
    blueSquareVY += 0.1

    # Do not capitalize the .get() method for pygame.event class
    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():
        if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    # Misspelled pygame.display
    pygame.display.update()
```

Hope this helped!

Comment: Ohhh Thank you !!XXXD That is  so nice of you to check my code and I learn a lot from it ! The original code is from Make Games with Python. 2-Raspberry(2016),page 22 and sorry again for my typos, I should check them carefully before paste.

Comment: @ruihuiliu Glad I could help! I read the book you mentioned above some time ago too. Don't forget to accept the answer if it fixed your problem.

Comment: Sure, I will ! It is the first time for me to use this website , so it took me several minutes to Bing out(google is banned) how to accept answer on stackoverflow,haha,thanks again !

Comment: hi, sorry for interoperation,would you like to give look at another problem I get fromMake Games with Python. Raspberry(2016)  if you have time? I am afraid this book did not provide correct code sample, here is my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48887664/is-there-anything-wrong-with-the-python-code-itself#