# Is there anything wrong with the Python code itself?

Tags: python, pygame

Here is the original code I copied from Make Games with Python.2-Raspberry Pi, page 33:

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS

# pygame variables
pygame.init()

windowWidth = 800
windowHeight = 800

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Keyboard!')

# square variables
playerSize = 20
playerX = (windowWidth / 2) - (playSize / 2)
playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
playerVX = 1.0
playerVY = 0.0
jumpHeight = 25.0
moveSpeed = 1.0
maxSpeed = 10.0
gravity = 1.0

#keybpard variables
leftDown = False
rightDown = False
haveJumped = False

def move():
    global playerX, playerY, playerVX, playerVY, haveJumped, gravity

    #move left
    if leftDown:
        # if we are already moving to the right,reset
        #the moving speed and invert the direction
        if playerVX > 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
            playerVX = -playerVX
        # make sure our square does not leave our
        #window to the left
        if playerX > 0:
           playerX += playerVX

    #move right
    if rightDown:
        #if we are already moving to the left,reset
        #the moving speed again
        if playerVX < 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
        #make sure our square does not leave our
        #window to the right
        if playerX + playerSize < windowWidth:
            playerX += playerVX

    if playerVY > 1.0:
        playerVY = player * 0.9
    else:
        playerVY = 0.0
        haveJumped - False

   # is our square in the air?
   # better add some gravity to bring it back down
    if playerY < windowHeight - playerSize:
        playerY += gravity
        gravity = gravity * 1.1
    else:
        playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
        gravity = 1.0

    playerY -= playerVY

    if (playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or
        (playerVX < 0.0 and playerVX > -maxSpeed):
        if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown)
            playerVX = playerVX * 1.1


# how to quit our program
def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

while True:
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,0,0),
    (playerX, playerY, playerSize, playerSize))

        #get a list of all enets that happened since
        #the last redraw
        for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():

            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

            if event.key == pygame.k_LEFT:
                leftDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = True
            if event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if not haveJumped:
                    haveJumped = True
                    playerVY += jumpHeight
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                quitGame()

        if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                leftDown = False
                playerVX = moveSpeed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = False
                playerVX = moveSpeed

    if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
        quitGame()

move()
pygame.display.update()
```

and there were many error indications when I debugged it, then I took advice given by nice interpal on website and added parentheses to fix the the error about "or" is invalid syntax and tried to rewrote code to fix the system:

```
import pygame, sys
import pygame.locals as GAME_GLOBALS
import pygame.event as GAME_EVENTS

# pygame variables
pygame.init()

windowWidth = 800
windowHeight = 800

surface = pygame.display.set_mode((windowWidth, windowHeight))
pygame.display.set_caption('Pygame Keyboard!')

# square variables
playerSize = 20
playerX = (windowWidth / 2) - (playSize / 2)
playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
playerVX = 1.0
playerVY = 0.0
jumpHeight = 25.0
moveSpeed = 1.0
maxSpeed = 10.0
gravity = 1.0

#keybpard variables
leftDown = False
rightDown = False
haveJumped = False

def move():
    global playerX, playerY, playerVX, playerVY, haveJumped, gravity

    #move left
    if leftDown:
        # if we are already moving to the right,reset
        #the moving speed and invert the direction
        if playerVX > 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
            playerVX = -playerVX
        # make sure our square does not leave our
        #window to the left
        if playerX > 0:
           playerX += playerVX

    #move right
    if rightDown:
        #if we are already moving to the left,reset
        #the moving speed again
        if playerVX < 0.0:
            playerVX = moveSpeed
        #make sure our square does not leave our
        #window to the right
        if playerX + playerSize < windowWidth:
            playerX += playerVX

    if playerVY > 1.0:
        playerVY = player * 0.9
    else:
        playerVY = 0.0
        haveJumped - False

   # is our square in the air?
   # better add some gravity to bring it back down
    if playerY < windowHeight - playerSize:
        playerY += gravity
        gravity = gravity * 1.1
    else:
        playerY = windowHeight - playerSize
        gravity = 1.0

    playerY -= playerVY

    if ((playerVX > 0.0 and playerVX < maxSpeed) or
        (playerVX < 0.0 and playerVX > -maxSpeed)):
        if not haveJumped and (leftDown or rightDown):
            playerVX = playerVX * 1.1


# how to quit our program
def quitGame():
    pygame.quit()
    sys.exit()

while True:
    surface.fill((0,0,0))
    pygame.draw.rect(surface, (255,0,0),
    (playerX, playerY, playerSize, playerSize))

        #get a list of all enets that happened since
        #the last redraw
    for event in GAME_EVENTS.get():

       if  event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:

           if  event.key == pygame.k_LEFT:
                leftDown = True
       if  event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = True
       if  event.key == pygame.K_UP:
                if not haveJumped:
                    haveJumped = True
                    playerVY += jumpHeight
       if (event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE):
                quitGame()

       if event.type == pygame.KEYUP:
            if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
                leftDown = False
                playerVX = moveSpeed
            if event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
                rightDown = False
                playerVX = moveSpeed

    if event.type == GAME_GLOBALS.QUIT:
        quitGame()

move()
pygame.display.update()
```

When I finally could run it, the result turned out to be a white screen window and informed new errors. I am a newbie of Python and coding, so I cannot even diagnose whether the code itself has problem (it is from a book).

The first new error is:

> E1101:Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member

And there are 13 errors on the list.

Would you take time to read the code and tell me whether the code itself is incorrect?

Comment: What are the new errors? Please add those into the question body, at the end, in a formatted block. Bear in mind that Stack Overflow is not a site where you can advertise for "free work" opportunities - people are happy to help, as long as you are aware you will be doing most of the implementation.

Comment: Thanks for your advice ! I will edit my question again, and sorry to say that I did not advertise for " free work " opportunities , maybe this is some mistake  exists ? And I feel sorry to post question to bother people here, I am self learning code and really eager for help.Thanks again!

Comment: Readers don't mind being bothered, people are happy to help. However, the first version of this was was "please fix it for me", which is basically a request for free work. Remember that everyone is a volunteer here, and adjust your expectations about how much effort to ask for, and you'll do fine.

Comment: Ohh then I apologize for my suck expression :) You know that I just get this code from a book and there is no commercial interest in it, I am afraid the code itself is incorrect as the errors informed in second time was different from the first time and I do wish to have volunteers who would like to run this code and to prove whether the code itself is wrong as my level is not high enough to diagnose it.

Comment: OK, no problem. As I asked above, **what are the new errors**?

Comment: The First new error isE1101:Module 'pygame' has no 'init' member, and 13 errors on the list. I feel lost because I did not write the code, I just copied down it as it is a sample on the book.

Comment: If you are getting a lot of errors, check what version of Python you are using, and what version is expected. I believe there were some major differences between 2.x and 3.x.

Comment: Hmm I am using python 3 and do you think the code itself is correct please ? I came across incorrect code on this book before, recommend you to read it (it is too easy for you):)

Comment: Well, what version is the book expecting? You've cited the title as `Make Games with Python.2-Raspberry Pi` - does "2" refer to the Python version? Please check the book now - it _will_ be in the text somewhere, probably in the introduction.

Comment: the book's whole name isMake Games with Python-Raspberry Pi on cover and I did once ran other code sample from it successfully except one piece which was proven to have logical error. And I am eager to know if this piece has logical error too。

Comment: My guess is that this number of problems in the code are _very_ unlikely, and a Python2/3 mismatch is _extremely_ likely. Please keep looking in the book! Or, alternatively, see if you have Python 2 installed, or install it.

Comment: I run it again on visual studio with python2.6.9 and nothing turns out , thanks anyway, sorry again for my stupid question failing to express my purpose, I just expect to get this code fixed and could see the result as dealing with it by myself is too hard, and I will try to find a new book and explore more about pygame .Thanks a lot !

Comment: No apologies needed. No question here is stupid, but you can often expect feedback about wording and detail on Stack Overflow. Good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is hard to tell, but it looks like Python 3 is in use, and I suspect the book is requiring Python 2. If you can re-run the program with Python 2, you may find you have far fewer errors (if any). If you do have a new error, you can then ask a new Stack Overflow question about that. Remember to be precise about the problem, and to include the error message(s) you get.